# send midi messages from C++

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, midi, alsa

I'm using a raspberry pi, so it is sort of Debian (Raspbian)

I have a synthesizer running (Zynaddsubfx) and I want to send him midi messages from code and have it playing the music for me. I will use ALSA for that.

I managed to create a "emitting port" in my program by doing:

```
snd_seq_create_simple_port(seq_handle, "My own sequencer",
    SND_SEQ_PORT_CAP_READ|SND_SEQ_PORT_CAP_SUBS_READ,
    SND_SEQ_PORT_TYPE_APPLICATION)
```

now I can see ZynSubAddFX in `aconnect -ol` and my own sequencer in `aconnect -il`. And I'm able to connect them:

```
pi@cacharro:~/projects/tests$ aconnect 129:0 128:0
pi@cacharro:~/projects/tests$ Info, alsa midi port connected
```

for doing that, as sugested by CL I used opened snd_seq_open, stored the sequence and then used snd_seq_create_simple_port.. BUT :

As commented before I just wanna send commands to zynsubaddfx under user interaction so creating queues, adding tempo and so on is not the way to go.

Is there a way to send simple midi comands like note on/note off through my opened port ???

Comment: Is this ZynAddSubFX compiled for Jack or OSS MIDI?

Comment: I updated my question with new detaisl, I guess the answer to you question is that it can work with all of three elements, the important one is ALSA, it seem to work properly for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send some events at a specific time:

- open the sequencer;
- create your own (source) port;
- construct and send some events.

To open the sequencer, call `snd_seq_open`.
(You can get your client number with `snd_seq_client_id`.)

```
    snd_seq_t seq;
    snd_seq_open(&seq, "default", SND_SEQ_OPEN_DUPLEX, 0);
```

To create a port, allocate a port info object with
`snd_seq_port_info_alloca`, set port parameters with
`snd_seq_port_info_set_`xxx, and `call snd_seq_create_port`.
Or simply call `snd_seq_create_simple_port`.

```
    int port;
    port = snd_seq_create_simple_port(seq, "my port",
            SND_SEQ_PORT_CAP_READ | SND_SEQ_POR_CAP_WRITE,
            SND_SEQ_PORT_TYPE_APPLICATION);
```

To send an event, allocate an event structure (just
for a change, you can use a local `snd_seq_event_t` variable),
and call various `snd_seq_ev_`xxx functions to set its properties.
Then call `snd_seq_event_output`, and `snd_seq_drain_output` after you've sent all
events.

```
    snd_seq_event_t ev;
    snd_seq_ev_clear(&ev);
    snd_seq_ev_set_direct(&ev);

    /* either */
    snd_seq_ev_set_dest(&ev, 64, 0); /* send to 64:0 */
    /* or */
    snd_seq_ev_set_subs(&ev);        /* send to subscribers of source port */

    snd_seq_ev_set_noteon(&ev, 0, 60, 127);
    snd_seq_event_output(seq, &ev);

    snd_seq_ev_set_noteon(&ev, 0, 67, 127);
    snd_seq_event_output(seq, &ev);

    snd_seq_drain_output(seq);
```

Comment: by far the most useful help I've received under this topic, If my instrument is ever ral stuff i will be opensource and your name will be there. thanks. Works like a charm