# How to have midi commands executed in real time from a Linux program

Tags: linux, real-time, midi

In Windows I have the `OpenMidi` `CloseMidi` and `SendMidi` commands.
After `OpenMidi` I get a handle and then I can use `SendMidi` to send midi messages like `90 52 64`, and I will hear a note on the default Acoustic Grand piano.

How would I do an equivalent action on Linux, executing midi commands at the time my program (such as a game) selects? This is performing in real time i.e. at the exact time the command is given.

Comment: What library implements that `SendMidi` command? And what library are you using in Linux?

Comment: The SendMidi command is readily available on most versions of Windows. Why do you ask? Regards the library in Linux: my question amounts to "what library in linux would supply a similar facility"?

Comment: My Windows doesn't have it. This is probably provided by your programming language, whatever it is. In any case, what to use in Linux depends on what programming language you're using there.

Comment: The programming language is irrelevant. I'm master of all weapons. I don't care about whether it is a program or a library. I want to find some real time capability with respect to midi, that's all.If you really must know, I run the SendMidi command from my own Forth 9ciforth). It is on a Toshiba with XP in some dll, and dll's can be called, as you know, from any language that's interfacing

Comment: Most sound cards do not have hardware synthesizers, and software synthesizers are not installed by default. Read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Midi/SoftwareSynthesisHowTo). I personally had success with Timidity++. Verify your setup by running `aplaymidi some-midi-file`. Then use one of the libraries mentioned in the answers, or repurpose `aplaymidi` source code.

Comment: I don't look for a software synthesizer. Can I be clearer than the question. I'm about to tentative answer my own question.

Comment: For those interested in Windows. The SendMidi is present in WINMM.DLL. I see this DLL from  a 2000 vintage XP system, as well in a Windows computer bought last year.  This suggests that sending real time midi messages  is pretty much a core facility in MS-Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search of my distribution's package list for the string "midi" offered at least two likely candidates:

- PortMidi - package name libportmidi0, homepage http://portmedia.sourceforge.net/
- RtMidi - package name librtmidi1, homepage http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/

Have you looked at these?

Comment: I want a 3byte midi packet send real time. I don't want to specify a call back with a time in the future to set in a buffer etc. BECAUSE THAT IS WHAT I'M DOING MYSELF IN MY PROGRAM. So portmidi is out.

Comment: The RtMidi packages provides the functionality. I can use that via a socket or wrapper, after writing an auxiliary program.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, the kernel's sound drivers and libraries are part of the [ALSA project](http://www.alsa-project.org/).

MIDI would be handled by the [sequencer API](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___sequencer.html), which is not very well documented.
([some example code in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21173379/11654))

In Python, use the `alsaseq` module from the alsa-python package.

In C++, you can try using the [RtMidi library](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/).

Answer (score 0):

A large part of the answers I've seen are beside the mark, as they require to specify the time to play a note, as opposed to sending an event in real time.
Apart from rtmid that is mentionned in answers here,
the approved answer to the linked question  "send midi messages from C++" is an answer to this question too,